# Qiita のページに載っているスクリプトのライセンスは？

Tags: ライセンス

Qiita のページを見ていると、そのままコピーして手元の開発に使いたくなるようなコードを見かけたりなどします。OSS系のソースを書いていた場合には、そのコピーしたコードを組み込みながら、レポジトリを公開したくなります。

## 質問

- Qiita に投稿されている記事の中の、ソースコードを利用するにあたってのライセンス的な規定はどうなっていますか？
- 特に、公開レポジトリに組み込むことはできますか？その場合の制約は何になりますか？

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Qiitaの利用規約には不明確な点があるので、Qiitaに問いあわせる必要があります。少なくとも「制限無く利用できる」という解釈は誤りです。

> 第9条(ユーザーによる投稿内容の取扱い)
>   2 ユーザーは、当社に対し、投稿内容について、無償にて利用(複製、複写、改変、第三者への再許諾その他のあらゆる利用を含む。)する権利を許諾するものとします。本項に基づく、ユーザーの当社への利用許諾の範囲には、本サービスを通じて、当社が他のユーザーに対して投稿内容の利用を再許諾することも含むものとします。特に、ユーザーは本サイトに投稿したコード、スニペットなどプログラムに類するものは他のユーザーが商用私用問わず使用することを許諾し、他のユーザーはこれを使用できるものとします。これにより、ユーザーは、本サービス上で他のユーザーが投稿した投稿内容を、当社の定める方法で編集、改変、複製することができるようになります。

最後の文がどこにかかっているのか、また「当社の定める方法」が何を指すのか不明です。

コードに対する定めにもこの文がかかっていると解釈すると、商用私用問わず使用することが許諾されていることにはなりますが、使用の方法については「当社の定める方法」に制限されます。

> 5 第2項から前項までの規定にかかわらず、ユーザは以下のライセンスに準拠する投稿内容を本サービスに投稿することができます。その場合、投稿内容の権利については当該ライセンスの定めに従うものとし、ユーザは投稿内容が当該ライセンスに違反していないことについて当社に保証するものとします。
>       (1)Creative Commons
>           (a)表示
>           (b)表示 - 継承
>       (2)GNU GPL
>       (3)BSDライセンス及び修正BSDライセンス
>       (4)前各号のライセンスに準ずるライセンスであって当社の認めるもの

投稿内容にこれらのライセンスが指定されている場合それらのライセンスによる制限が発生します。

Comment: ポイントは、 qiita へ「ユーザーへの、再配布許可しながらの配布」の権利を、投稿者は与えていることになるが、 qiita が実際どうその他ユーザーに配布するかは、記述されていない(と解釈できる) だと理解しました

Answer (score 4):

すでに引用がある箇所を解釈すると

投稿者Aの投稿した記事のうち

1. Qiitaで認められているライセンスの明示がある場合=>それに従う
2. 記事中に含まれる**ソースコードの類**=>`商用私用問わず使用することを許諾`
3. ソースコード類ではない記事部分(解説文章等)=>Qiitaの編集リクエスト機能のように編集、改変、複製できる

となります。

@suzukis 氏は

> 少なくとも「制限無く利用できる」という解釈は誤りです。

と書かれていますが**特に投稿者がQiitaで認められているライセンスを明示していない場合制限なく利用できる**、と解するべきでしょう。ただ気になるのはCCで言うところのBYの部分ですね。SAとNCとNDは否定されていますが・・・。

@user20098 氏は

> 投稿内容が著作権等に違反していないのが前提ですが

と書いていますがこれは語弊があり、正確には

1. 記事が二次利用の場合→許諾なしでの二次利用なら記事そのものがアウト、許諾ありなら上記解釈どおり
2. 記事が二次創作の場合→二次創作物としての記事は上記解釈に従うと**同時に**一次創作物の許諾条件の制約を受ける

が留意するべき点です。

---

> CC 系などが明記してあれば、著作者がライセンスを直指定しているので、多分普通に web サイトで CC などで公開されているのと同じ扱いで良い気がしています。

上述のとおり明示されたライセンスがQiita指定のものならばそれに従う

> 何も指定がなかった場合は、ちょっと確認の必要がありそうだ、と思って‌​ます。

上述 `2.`, `3.`のとおり

Comment: CC 系などが明記してあれば、著作者がライセンスを直指定しているので、多分普通に web サイトで CC などで公開されているのと同じ扱いで良い気がしています。何も指定がなかった場合は、ちょっと確認の必要がありそうだ、と思ってます。

Answer (score 1):

Qiitaの規約については、Qiitaに確認するのが確実です、という点に留意の上で、
公開されている情報([Qiitaの利用規約ページ](https://qiita.com/terms))にそれらしい記載がありましたので、引用しておきます。

> 第9条(ユーザーによる投稿内容の取扱い)
>   2. ユーザーは、当社に対し、投稿内容について、無償にて利用(複製、複写、改変、第三者への再許諾その他のあらゆる利用を含む。)する権利を許諾するものとします。本項に基づく、ユーザーの当社への利用許諾の範囲には、本サービスを通じて、当社が他のユーザーに対して投稿内容の利用を再許諾することも含むものとします。特に、ユーザーは本サイトに投稿したコード、スニペットなどプログラムに類するものは他のユーザーが商用私用問わず使用することを許諾し、他のユーザーはこれを使用できるものとします。これにより、ユーザーは、本サービス上で他のユーザーが投稿した投稿内容を、当社の定める方法で編集、改変、複製することができるようになります。

投稿内容が著作権等に違反していないのが前提ですが、投稿内容は制限なく利用できる、と記載されていると思います。

Answer (score 1):

解決ずみになっていますが、質問内容と回答が気になったので・・・

> 公開レポジトリに組み込むことはできますか？その場合の制約は何になりますか？

最近、英語圏のオープンソースプロジェクトでは ライセンスに気を付けて作業している事が多いようです。
Linux カーネルや git 等では コミットの下に

```
Signed-off-by: ユーザ名 <メールアドレス>
```

のような署名を付けて、開発者による コードのライセンスの正当性を確認したものだけを
取り込むようにしています。

[OSSコミュニティのリスク対策](http://ossforum.jp/node/803)

にも書かれていますが、開発者によってライセンスの明示されていないソースは 利用しないことが
安全だと思います。

---

Qiita の利用規約では 投稿できるけど、投稿者に責任があると明記しています。
投稿者が ライセンスを明記していない投稿は 利用しない方が安全です。

[利用規約 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/terms) より 投稿者の責任に関する部分を抜粋

> 第7条(ユーザーの責任)
>   5.ユーザーが他人の名誉を毀損した場合、プライバシー権を侵害した場合、著作権法に違反する行為を行った場合、その他他人の権利を侵害した場合、当該ユーザーは自身の責任と費用において解決しなければならず、当社は一切の責任を負いません。
>   6.ユーザーが、他者及びユーザー自身が本サービス上に投稿、コメントした情報やプログラムの使用によって不利益が生じた場合、当該ユーザー自身に責任があるものとし、当社は一切の責任を負いません。
>
> 第8条(禁止事項)
>   4.ユーザーは、本サービスの「Qiita」を利用するに際し、以下のような行為を行ってはなりません。 
>   (1)他者の著作権や機密情報、その他の権利を侵害する情報を掲載する行為
>
> 第9条(ユーザーによる投稿内容の取扱い)
>   1.ユーザーは、本サービスを利用して本サイト上に投稿した投稿、コメント、公開プロフィールの自己紹介などのテキストデータ、および画像や動画・音声ファイルなどの投稿テキストに付随的に投稿されたデータ(以下「投稿内容」といいます。)について、自らが投稿又は送信することについての適法な権利を有していること、及び投稿内容が第三者の権利を侵害しないことについて、表明し、保証するものとします。

---

ちなみに stackoverflow は投稿する内容は 
[CC-BY-SAクリエイティブコモンズライセンス条項](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
に違反しないことと、投稿者が著作者であるもの を制約としているように
（Google 翻訳した日本語では）読み取れます。

一部でも GPL のソースを コピー＆ペーストして 回答してはいけません。

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287986/posting-gpl-code-in-an-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1
を Google 翻訳した抜粋

```
要するに：いいえ、ここにGPLコードを投稿することはできません。

FSF は、CC-BY-SAがGPLと互換性がないと見なします
（ページ上部のキーに示されているように、ページの左側にある黄色の破線はこれを示します）。
これは、事実を立証する実際の裁判とは異なりますが、次善策です。

Stack Exchangeの利用規約では、CC-BY-SAに基づくすべての貢献のライセンスを取得する必要があります。
選ぶことはできません（つまり、「このコードはGPLですが、私の答えの残りはCC-BY-SAです」）。

投稿の小さなサンプルコードの量は、4つの要因に応じて、公正使用の下で法的かもしれません。
しかし、これは複雑な問題であり、プログラマーはしばしば間違いを犯します
（特に、コメントを読まずにメタ投稿にリンクされているものを支持することによって）。

フェアユースは常にケースバイケースで評価されます。
つまり、あなたが明確にいることを絶対に確認する唯一の方法は、訴えられて勝つことです。
おそらくそれはしたくないでしょう。
```

Comment: git のコミットへの署名はあくまでコミットしたユーザーの正当性 (=なりすまし等がないか) を確認するものであり、ライセンスの話とは直接関連が無いように思います。

Comment: Linux の パッチを送信するときには、[カーネルパッチ作成・投稿に関する指針](http://archive.linux.or.jp/JF/JFdocs/kernel-docs-2.6/SubmittingPatches.html)  にあるように 『「 sign-off 」とは、パッチがあなたの書いたものであるか、あるいは、あなたがそのパッチをオープンソースとして提供する権利を保持している、
という証明をパッチの説明の末尾に一行記載するというものです。（当該プロジェクト又は関連する オープンソースライセンスに沿った形で再配布されることに理解及び 同意する。 ・・途中省略・・） もしこれに同意できるなら、以下のような1行を追加してください。  Signed-off-by: Random J Developer <random@developer.example.org>  』と書かれています。 signed-off は英語圏のビジネス文書を承認する用途で利用する言葉らしいです。